# Can I use the verb do with Nobody?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

My friend told us in a group conversation that "Don't take me wrong guys". While replying to this, is the use of the sentence "Nobody do" is correct in this reference? I know that "Nobody" is an indefinite pronoun and is used as a singular notation but here in the reply "Nobody do" I am referring to a plural action of everyone's doing.

Comment: Nobody does it.

Comment: @HotLicks Well played, good sir. Well played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indefinite pronouns can be tricky. *Nobody*, *anybody*, *somebody*, and *everybody* (and their *-one*, *-thing* and *-where* counterparts, and a few others) are [generally treated as singular](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/no-one-nobody-nothing-nowhere), even if they refer to something obviously plural.

> In America, where two-thirds of the population believe that everyone has an equal chance to get ahead, far fewer people favour income redistribution than in Europe. <sub><sup>(“[Meritocracy and its discontents](https://www.economist.com/node/7961962),” *The Economist*, Oct. 5, 2006)</sup></sub>
>
> Everybody is chatting: Three women are exchanging tips about throwing a product-launch event. Two twentysomethings are discussing a tricky coding problem over a ping-pong match. <sub><sup>Segran, Elizabeth, “[As Coworking Spaces Scale, Can They Keep Their Communal Vibe?](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2015/02/as-coworking-spaces-scale-can-they-keep-their-communal-vibe/385653/)” *The Atlantic*, Feb. 27, 2015</sup></sub>

Other indefinite pronouns, like *all* or *some*, may be singular or plural depending on the context.

---

*Don't take me wrong, guys* would not be idiomatic in American English, though it seems to be used in Indian English. The usual AmE formulation to urge against misunderstanding would be *Don't get me wrong, guys* or *Don't take me/this the wrong way, guys*, with the latter a frequent cliché employed before delivering something disheartening or disappointing to the listener like a criticism.

Regardless, if you want to indicate that the sentiment is universally disavowed by the group, you could respond

> - Nobody does
> - No one does
> - None of us does
> - None of us do

Comment: And "neither one of us does"

Comment: None of us could be singular and plural?

Comment: @Ives Yes, [*none* can be used either as a singular or plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/); it is singular if the sense is *not one*, plural if the sense is *not any*. Consider *[And Then There Were None](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Then_There_Were_None)*.