# Nobody asks me or Nobody ask me? Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

> Nobody asks me

Or

> Nobody ask me

> Everybody ask me

Or

> Everybody asks me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the verb do with Nobody?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168732/can-i-use-the-verb-do-with-nobody) Also [Which is correct “no one does” or “no one do”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/218362/which-is-correct-no-one-does-or-no-one-do)

Answer (score 5):

"Nobody" is singular, so for the simple statement of fact "Nobody asks me".

> Nobody asks me for advice on building the engine, even though I'm the only person who understands how a carburettor works

However, you can also form imperative expressions, in which the verb has its basic form

> I'm concentrating.  Be quiet!  Don't distract me!  Nobody ask me any questions!

Answer (score 0):

In fact they are all **singular pronouns** so we use them as a **singular subject**.

> In English grammar, the third-person singular verb ending is the
> suffix -s or -es that's conventionally added to the base form of a
> verb in the **present tense** when it follows a **singular subject** in the
> third person

Everyone **knows** who stole it, but they're all afraid to.

Nobody ever **says** they want to become a cop so they can bust people for drinking alcohol etc.